# Get some data from sql

Tags: mysql

I have 4 tables:

```
pracownicy

    z a
    trybutami:
    NR_PRAC
    int NOT NULL,
    NAZWISKO char(15),
    PLEC char(1) NOT NULL,
    DATA_UR datetime ,
    NR_ZESP
    smallint NOT NULL

    zespoły
    z atrybutami:
    NR_ZESP
    smallint NOT NULL,
    NAZWA_ZESP char(30) NOT NULL,
    NR_PRAC_KZ int

    tematy
    z atrybutami:
    NR_TEM
    int NOT
    NULL,
    DATA_ROZP datetime,
    DATA_ODB datetime ,
    NR_PRAC_KT int,
    TEMAT char(30) NOT NULL,

    wypłaty
    z atrybutami
    :
    NR_PRAC int NOT NULL,
    NR_TEM int NOT NULL,
    DATA_NALICZ datetime NOT NULL,
    DATA_WYPL datetime,
    KWOTA decimal(10, 1) NOT NULL
```

Now I want to get the youngest pracownik from every zespol. How can I do that? 
This is my try:

```
Select pracownicy.nazwisko, pracownicy.data_ur from pracownicy inner join zespoly on pracownicy.nr_zesp = zespoly.nr_zesp;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [The "first past the post election" query problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474336/the-first-past-the-post-election-query-problem)

Comment: What you are trying to do is a correlated subquery. Take a look at the question I posted years ago for inspiration.